# java.lang.IllegalStateException: onGetLayoutInflater() cannot be executed until the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi I am trying to implement native Ads in my Android App so I have [this code](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/java/admob/NativeAdvancedExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/gms/nativeadvancedexample/MainActivity.java) , you can check the source code in Github.

It does sometimes fire this error in Logcat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.august_themes.free_fast_stock_inventory_manager, PID: 3234
java.lang.IllegalStateException: onGetLayoutInflater() cannot be executed until the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1503)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1452)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1484)
```

The error happens when this code is executed :

```
  private void refreshAd() {
    refresh.setEnabled(false);

    AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.AdmobNativeAdsID));

    builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
        // OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener implementation.
        @Override
        public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
            // You must call destroy on old ads when you are done with them,
            // otherwise you will have a memory leak.
            if (nativeAd != null) {
                nativeAd.destroy();
            }
            nativeAd = unifiedNativeAd;
            FrameLayout frameLayout =
                    v.findViewById(R.id.nativeads_adplaceholder);
            UnifiedNativeAdView adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null);
            populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
            frameLayout.removeAllViews();
            frameLayout.addView(adView);
        }

    });
```

We are talking about this line of code

```
  UnifiedNativeAdView adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null);
```

***Hence my question :***
**Can I test something like implement condition to make sure that the Fragment is attached to the Fragment Manager before calling this function getLayoutInflater() ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your question according to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) fragment has `.isAdded()` function that Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks man. got rid of the error by checking  if (isAdded()) { before inflating ads.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. @Aness

Comment: Thanks for the answer, solved my problem.